Exporting with darktable
I recently moved from lightroom to darktable and I don't know how to save changes in an image to be able to see them in other programs or in windows file explorer.

When I edit JPG, I first tried to export the images, but then I had all images duplicated taking space of my disk.
Then I tried to export them with overwrite, which helped me viewing the edited photos outside darktable, but also being able to continue editing or modifying them at any time. The problem is that when I close darktable and open it again other day, all the edits are done twice on my image, and the one that darktable takes as original is the edited one. Now my images are good outside darktable, but not inside darktable, where they are over-edited.

I was wondering if there is a way to have my images edited outside and inside darktable, but also be able to use darktable as a file explorer to see my images and their history. Something like with lightroom.

It's not an answer to your question, hence a comment, but is there a reason (apart from "that's the way Lightroom does it") why you want to do file management in Darktable? I tend to keep the Lightable clear unless I'm in the process of editing and do my viewing and file management in DigiKam (many other viewers/managers are available). But then, I'm a separate-turntable-and-amplifier kind of guy, so I'm not looking for one thing to rule them all.

I just don't like to have many applications. Besides,I like organizing and tagging my photos. If I used another program for file management I would have to export and duplicate my images to have them tagged, if I'm not wrong

In fact, Im' just trying to find a good workflow. I don't even know if I should just export to JPG and not save the RAWs after editing. Any suggestion will be appreciated

No matter which editing software you are using, it is a bad idea to overwrite the original file with your changes. You should always keep the original around because you might want to make different changes at a later point, e.g. because you made a mistake or because you have learned a new editing technique.
So your first approach was right: you should export your files from darktable, which will result in you having the original file and the edited one separately. You can export them into the same directory or a different one, I suspect most people do the latter and have a directory just for edited files. If disk space is such a major problem for you, obviously you can delete one of the files when you think no longer need it, but disk space is actually fairly cheap nowadays.
Your second approach is definitely not how you are meant to use darktable: the xmp file describes the edits to the original image, you overwrote that with the edited one, so now it is applying the edits described by the xmp file to the already edited file. The result is wrong for obvious reasons.
darktable, is, according to its own FAQ, not a file manager. (I actually remembered a differently worded version of that.) I can't answer about "like with Lightroom" because I have never used Lightroom; you shouldn't assume everyone has.

darktable is an example of a non-destructive photograph editor, primarily for raw images but it can be used with other formats such as jpg's. The non-destructive workflow is based on the methods familiar to analogue film photographers from before the digital camera era.

Think of the camera raw / jpg as the film negative. This is kept as an archive of the original image capture. The image editor then becomes analogous to the darkroom where negatives are selected for printing and edits are made with techniques to crop, dodge and burn etc. The photographer may even write notes on the back of the print, or on a slip of paper kept paper-clipped to it. Several test prints exploring different approaches may be made until the final print is created which may be framed and displayed (or put in a drawer and forgotten about).
With darktable, the edits you make are merely a list of instructions which are kept in the database and .xmp sidecar file (the paper_clipped note) as a recipe for processing the file. This allows the edits to be undone to any stage of the editing history at anytime. The programme uses this recipe to show you the image on screen, re-processing it all whenever you make a change. This explains why you need a powerful computer to create complicated edits on large files in raw editors and is the trade off for being to move up and down that editing history stack so freely. If you open one of the sidecar files in a text editor you can see the instructions written out in addition to the camera metadata for things like aperture, shutter speed and any comments, titles, descriptions and keyword tags you may have entered.
At this point whilst other programmes can read the sidecar the pipeline instructions, which are darktable specific are meaningless to them. They do not have the tools to make the recipe work. It is only when you export an image from darktable that everything comes together and the final image (usually a .jpg file) is formed with metadata embedded and all the edits fixed. This also acts as a backup which is good practice in computing, provided the original and edit are kept separately. In an ideal world this would be on a different device in a different location, but we're not talking about crucial, internationally important data here are we? A separate hard drive is a good start. As for HDD space, a 1TB drive will set you back less than £50 and hold more 130,000 8Mb jpg's. That should keep you going for a while.
